# my sql select query with table name in french language

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `aset_catégorie` and when I try to run a select query I'm getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '©gorie' at line 1

How do I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried enclosing your table name in backticks? Like this: `\`aset_catégorie\``

Comment: Cant you just rename your table ? its so stupid having special caracters for a table name...

Comment: i know but its my clients project not mine i suggested him but he is like he wants it in french so....... and my query is simple   "SELECT * FROM aset_catégorie"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `aset_catégorie`
```

You might have missed

> ` (backtick)

sign...

Hope this helps

Comment: did that trick but didnt work i also tried [aset_catégorie] but still got the same error..

Comment: SELECT * FROM aset_catégorie